# Is Linear Independence based on a coordinate system?

Tags: linear-algebra

Having trouble with a question that asks me to show that vectors [1,1,0], [1,0,1], and [0,1,1] are linearly dependent in $F^{3}_{2}$.

Where $F^{3}_{2}$ is defined as the set of vectors [a,b,c] where a,b,c = {0,1}. I am confused as to what this is asking and would appreciate some clarification.

I understand that in these vectors are linearly independent in $R^{3}$ since we can show that the only solution for $$a1v1 + a2v2 + a3v3 = 0$$ is when a1=a2=a3=0

Comment: I assume that the field of scalars for your vector space $F$ is $F_2$, the field with two elements. As a warm-up problem, can you compute $[1,1,0] + [1,0,1]$?

Comment: that would be [2, 1, 1]

Comment: It seems that $F=\{0,1\}$, the field with 2 element. In this field $1+1=0$. Try the linear combination $1 [1,1,0]+1[1,0,1]+1 [0,1,1]$.

Comment: If I'm interpreting the problem correctly, then I believe that if $[a,b,c] \in F$ then, $a,b$, and $c$ are elements of $F_2$, the field with two elements. Addition of vectors in $F$ uses the addition operation in $F_2$, so that $[1,1,0] + [1,0,1] = [0,1,1]$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger But, the letter $F$ has already been used for something else, so we should use a different name for the field with two elements. (For example we could call it $F_2$.)

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. But yes $F_{2}$ is the set of vectors [a b c], where a, b, c ∈ $F_{2}$ ={0,1}. Thanks for the response, but still a bit unclear about what your comment is getting at?

Comment: Well, $[2,1,1]$ is not the correct answer to the warm-up problem, and this is something that needs to be understood as a first step.

Comment: I thought addition of vectors was just element-wise?

Comment: When we do arithmetic in $F_2$, the field with two elements, $1 + 1 = 0$. So, $[1,1,0] + [1,0,1] = [0,1,1]$. We have to get used to doing arithmetic in $F_2$.

Comment: If we wanted to be more precise, we could say that addition in $F$ is defined so that $[a_1,a_2,a_3] + [b_1,b_2,b_3] = [a_1 \bigoplus b_1, a_2 \bigoplus b_2, a_3 \bigoplus b_3]$, where $\bigoplus$ is the addition operator on $F_2$, the field with two elements. Note that $1 \bigoplus 1 = 0$. The operator $\bigoplus$ is not the normal addition operator that we are used to when working with integers or real numbers. So, $[1,1,0] + [1,0,1] = [1 \bigoplus 1, 1 \bigoplus 0, 0 \bigoplus 1] = [0,1,1]$.

Comment: huh I guess I need to take a step back and understand that first. Can you help explain how to understand addition in $F_{2}$?

Comment: You may have already learned how to do addition and multiplication mod $n$, where $n$ is a positive integer. For example, if we do arithmetic mod $5$, then we have five numbers $0,1,2,3,4$ in our number system, and for example $3  \bigoplus 4 = 2$. It's possible to show that this number system is a field. If we instead do arithmetic mod $2$, then we have only two numbers ($0$ and $1$) in our number system. You can show that this number system also forms a field -- a field with just two elements. This field with two elements is named $F_2$.

Comment: Oh that's making more sense, the problem specifies "$F^{3}_{2}$ is the set of vectors [a b c] where a, b, c ∈ $F_{2}$ ={0,1}", which I thought was just the set of vectors {[0,0,0] , [1,0,0], [0,1,0],...,[1,1,1]}